# Play 2.2.2 with SBT sub projects and Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I'm trying to setup multi-module dev environment with Play 2.2.2 and SBT 0.13.1

My project structure looks like this:

```
myProject
 └ build.sbt
 └ app - this code works perfect
 └ modules
   └ testModule
     └ build.sbt
     └ src
       └ main
         └ scala - here I have simple object Foo with method which returns string
       └ test
         └ scala - here is Spec2 test for Foo object with JUnitRunner
 └ test - here is Spec2 tests for app and these tests also works fine
```

build.sbt in the root contains:

```scala
import play.Project._

name := "FooBar"

version := "1.0"

playScalaSettings

lazy val main = project.in(file("."))
  .dependsOn(testModule).aggregate(testModule)

lazy val testModule = project.in(file("modules/testModule"))
```

build.sbt in module contains only:

```scala
import play.Project._

name := "FooBar-module"

playScalaSettings
```

When I'm trying to use code from testModule, compiler told me that it cannot find even packages from this module. Also while running tests I got

> No tests to run for testModule/test:test

But if I write invalid code in testModule, I will start to get errors from this module, so module is definitely compiled.

What could be a problem here? SBT config looks correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`playScalaSettings`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlaySettings.scala) contains settings for most of the paths. This includes that the test source are set to the path `/test` (See [default settings in doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/SBTSettings)). In your layout however, the test sources are located in `src/test`. So sbt will not look for these files in test.

If your module is a play project then either change the folder layout accordingly or configure the paths to match your layout. If not remove the `playScalaSettings` line.

You can set the test source path like this:

```
scalaSource in Test <<= baseDirectory / "src" / "test" / "scala"
```

Comment: Yes, I changed directories as in playScalaSettings and everything works - both test and app! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Regarding .aggregate(testModule): without aggregation, in case of test on main project, test won't be runned on subproject

Comment: @ViLPy: Oh, didn't realize that. I'll remove that part from the question. Glad, I could help.